# Chrome Extension Developer - how to match content script urls from user specified websites?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome

As the title says, how would i implement that the content script would be injected according to user specified websites?

Right now i'm saving user specified websites in a Storage.

I tried doing it programmatically by injecting content script upon tab creation/update but i had issues with cross origin stuff, and couldn't get it to work.

```
const injectContentScripts = function(sites)
{
    // if not provided, use default.
    if (!sites)
        sites = 'website.com'

    const urls = sites.split('\n').map(url => `*://${url}/*`)

    chrome.tabs.query({ url:urls, status:'complete' }, function(tabs) {

        for (const tab of tabs)
        {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file:'ext/jquery.min.js', allFrames:true, runAt:'document_end' }, function(){

                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file:'content.js', allFrames:true, runAt:'document_end' })

            })
        }

    })
}
```

I also had an idea i could just format manifest.json file upon user updating what websites user would like to add but that wouldn't work as when you pack an extension it becomes that .crx file or somethiing, right?

I tried searching about this case but couldn't find anyone asking this. Sorry if i'm missing something, i'm not that great in English.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would strongly advise you to reformat your answer, braking this wall of text into logical blocks and *add relevant program code*.

Comment: updated it, and actually found of what i had before @ITDesigns.eu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found solution myself. :D

Well, if anyone needs something like this as well. I got it working with this,

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(async (e) => {

    const saved = await chrome.storage.sync.get(['sites'])

    // if not provided, use default.
    if (!saved.sites)
        saved.sites = 'website.com'    

    const split = e.url.split('://')
    const splitUrl = split[1] ? split[1].split('/')[0] : false

    // if not url or frame is not main frame return.
    if (!splitUrl || e.frameId != 0)
        return

    for (const url of saved.sites.split('\n'))
    {
        if (splitUrl.match(url))
        {
            injectContentScripts(e.tabId)
            break;
        }
    }

})

const injectContentScripts = async function(tabId)
{
    if (tabId == undefined)
        return

    try {
        // i'm using this npm library, whichh allows async await https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-extension-async
        await chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file:'ext/jquery.min.js', allFrames:true, runAt:'document_end' })
        await chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file:'content.js', allFrames:true, runAt:'document_end' })
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```

There is integrated url matcher, but i wasn't sure how i could access those functions. Anyway this works fine, cleaner way would be with RegExp but it works so it's fine i guess. :D

In order this to work, you have to specify these permissions in manifest file.

```
"permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "<all_urls>"
],
```